# better way to replace string with various scenarios in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, object, replace

How to replace special characters for different pattern of same string in javascript

am passing one string at a time and below are string patterns

```
var str1="2456 #02-567"
var result = str1.replace(/#/g, '')

var str1="2-567 2456"
var result = str1.replace(/^/g, '0')
```

```
for these strings

2456 #02-567 , 2456 02-567, 2456 2-567,2456 #2-567

Expected Output 
2456 02-567 
 ===========
for these strings
#02-567 2456 , 2-567 2456, 02-567 2456, #2-567 2456

Expected Output 
02-567 2456
```

Comment: So, you want to apply two different patterns to the same string?

Comment: 1. You do not have `^` in your example string 2. It seems you also want to deduplicate the  result? Also `^` has a special meaning of start of string in regexps

Answer (score 1):

May be there is a clever solution, but this should work:

```js
let str = ["2456 #02-567" , "2456 02-567", "2456 2-567","2456 #2-567","#02-567 2456" , "2-567 2456", "02-567 2456", "#2-567 2456","1234 12-345","1234 #12-345","#12-345 1234"];
//1234 12-345" or "1234 #12-345" or "#12-345 1234"
for(let st of str)
 console.log(st.replace(/#?(\d)?(\d-)/g ,replacer))
 
 function replacer(match, p1, p2, offset, string){
  let replaceSubString = p1 || "0";
  replaceSubString += p2;
  return replaceSubString;
 }
```

I'm using a captouring group (expression in the parenthesis in the regular expression) that can be referenced in the second parameter of `replace` function with `$1` (1 because is the first captouring group).  The `?` instead point that the character is optional.

Comment: thanks for reply, when i tried similar pattern string but different numbers for example "1234 12-345" or "1234 #12-345" or "#12-345 1234" it should show "1234 12-345" not working, can help please

Comment: The problem is that you haven't clearly defined your goal.  I modified the answer, but the last case isn't matched because it's not enough defined your target. Starting from my answer you can work out by yourself what you need otherwise define the problem better.

Comment: okay thanks Umbert